# In C#, what is the `?` in the type `DateTime?`

Tags: c#, nullable

I just ran across some code while working with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

```
public DateTime? LastLogon { get; }
```

What is the ? after the DateTime for.

I found a reference for the [?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), but it's not the same thing. (280Z28: Here is the correct link for [Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).)

Comment: There are a lot of nullable types in C# now.
But be careful Null is not 0.

Comment: The link in your post is actually to the ?? operator, which is the unrelated but very cool null coalescing operator.

Comment: Read section 4.1.10 of the C# specification for details.

Comment: @Charlie: I think it was a duplicate in sheep's clothing until I reworded it in the title.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `?` makes it a nullable type (it's shorthand for the `Nullable<T>` Structure and is applicable to all value types).

[Nullable Types (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx)

Note:

The `??` you linked to is the null coalescing operator which is completely different.

Comment: I think one of the most important things to point out here is that this is not special to the DateTime type. It works for int, decimal and other usually not-nullable types as well and in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

The `?` is not an operator in this case, it's part of the type. The syntax

```
DateTime?
```

is short for

```
Nullable<DateTime>
```

so it declares that `LastLogon` is a property that will return a `Nullable<DateTime>`. For details, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

The `??` that you [linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to is somewhat relevant here. That is the null-coalescing operator which has the following semantics. The expression

```
x ?? y
```

evaluates to `y` if `x` is `null` otherwise it evaluates to `x`. Here `x` can be a reference type or a nullable type.

Answer (score 0):

shorthand for

```
Nullable<DateTime>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a shortcut for `Nullable<DateTime>`.  Be aware that methods using these types can't be exposed to COM as they are use generics despite looking like they don't.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned this ? syntax makes the type nullable.

A couple of key things to keep in mind when working with nullable types (taken from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx), but I thought it would be helpful to call them out here):

- You commonly use the read-only properties `Value` and `HasValue` when working with nullable types.

e.g.

```
int? num = null;
if (num.HasValue == true)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("num = " + num.Value);
}
```

- You can use the null coalescing operator to assign a default value to a nullable type. This is very handy.

e.g.

```
int? x = null;
int y = x ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `?` is used for [declaring a value type as nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx).

This is great in a couple of situations:

- When pulling data from a database that has a null value stored in a nullable field (that maps to a .NET value type)
- When you need to represent "not specified" or "not found".

For example, consider a class used to represent feedback from a customer who was asked a set of non-mandatory questions:

```
class CustomerFeedback
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int? Age { get; set; }
    bool? DrinksRegularly { get; set; }
}
```

The use of nullable types for `Age` and `DrinksRegularly` can be used to indicate that the customer did not answer these questions.

In the example you cite I would take a `null` value for `LastLogon` to mean that the user has never logged on.