# What does the ? mean after a type?

Tags: c#, syntax, types, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [a curious c# syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069863/a-curious-c-syntax)

So I've seen some code around and a few of them use a ? after the type, like this:

```
private Point? loc = null;
```

So I'm wondering if Point? is different than Point (can't put a question mark at the end of my sentence or I'll confuse you guys ... :] ). The language I'm using is C# by the way.

Comment: To write "code" inside normal sentences, use backticks, ` to flag text as "code". In this way, you can use angle brackets, and if you had put the question mark inside, you wouldn't have confused anyone either.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069863/a-curious-c-syntax/2069873#2069873

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`T?` is a shorthand (in C#) for `Nullable<T>` - so `Point?` is another way of writing `Nullable<Point>` or example.

See sections 1.3 and 4.1 of the C# 3 language spec - and various other places, to be honest - for more details. See the docs for [`System.Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) for more information from the framework side of things. Or read chapter 4 of C# in Depth :) (Unfortunately it's not one of the free chapters.)

(This question is bound to be a duplicate, but I don't have the energy to find it right now.)

Comment: It is indeed a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069863/a-curious-c-syntax/2069873#2069873

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072482/in-c-what-is-the-in-the-type-datetime

Comment: Knew it was somewhere, but couldn't find it (I don't think the search can handle ? very well and I had no clue it was nullable... Sorry guys.

Answer (score 2):

`Point?` is the same as `Nullable<Point>`. It allows you to assign `null` to value types, such as `struct`s.

Answer (score 0):

It means the type can accept its' value and null.