# What does a questionmark (?) mean in a function declaration in C#

Tags: c#, syntax, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “DateTime?” mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109859/what-does-datetime-mean-in-c)
>   [What does the ? mean after a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079334/what-does-the-mean-after-a-type)

I had a function declaration including a questionmark after the datatype like:

```
private TimeSpan? sometime()
{

}
```

What does this mean?

Comment: yes it is equal to Nullable<TimeSpan>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`TimeSpan?` is shorthand for `System.Nullable<TimeSpan>`.

A `TimeSpan` is a value type, which cannot take a `null` value. By wrapping it in a `System.Nullable<>` it can be `null`. Without that `?` it would be illegal to return `null` from the function.

Answer (score 4):

[Nullable Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

> Represents an object whose underlying type is a value type that can
>   also be assigned null like a reference type.

Instead of writing `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, you can write `TimeSpan?`.

Answer (score 2):

Nullable, that a value type can be null.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the value type is a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Basically its a nullable TimeStamp.