# <Bind(Exclude:="CurrentPrice")> Not Working in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing this in ASP.NET MVC 4 and have been trying to have have a field in the form where one of the fields are excluded from being written into. I have the following model in the AuctionsController.vb file, which controls the form:

```
Function Create(<Bind(Exclude:="CurrentPrice")> test_auction As Models.Auction) As ActionResult
            Dim categoryList = New SelectList(New Object() {"Automotive", "Electronics", "Games", "Home"})
            ViewBag.CategoryList = categoryList
            Return View()
        End Function
```

This is what the view, Create.vbhtml, looks like:

```
lType MVCAuction.Models.Auction

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Create"
End Code

<h2>Create</h2>

@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @*@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)

    @<fieldset>
        <legend>Auction</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Category)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Category)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Category, DirectCast(ViewBag.CategoryList, SelectList))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Category)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.ImageURL)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ImageURL)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ImageURL)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.StartTime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.StartTime)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.StartTime)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.EndTime)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.EndTime)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.EndTime)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.StartPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.StartPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.StartPrice)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.CurrentPrice)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.CurrentPrice)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CurrentPrice)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
End Using

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@Section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
End Section
```

When I go into the form in the browser and enter data, it still says "The (name of variable) is required"; as seen below:
 [image: the field is still required]

Why is the bind exclude function not working?

Answer (score 1):

As I was doing the tutorial, I realized the `<Bind(Exclude:="CurrentPrice")>` part of the Create function in the AuctionsController wasn't the issue that caused the CurrentPrice field to still be required.

Although I'm using MVC 4 and not C#, the post here answered my question: [What does a questionmark (?) mean in a function declaration in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802798/what-does-a-questionmark-mean-in-a-function-declaration-in-c-sharp)

Which is to use the question mark around the variable type, like: `Decimal?` so it has the variable not be required when the user goes to fill out the form on the web page.

Hopefully this helps someone that has the same issue as I had!